# Наголос: фЕйсбук чи фейсбУк?

Tags: наголос

Як правильно поставити наголос у слові "фейсбук"? На телебачені та по радіо наголос роблять на першому складі, а в повсякденому житті - навпаки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За анґлійськими словниками — на перший склад:

> `/ˈfeɪs.bʊk/`

Тобто *Ф**е́**йсбук*.

---

Словники з озвуком

- [Cambridge](//dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/facebook)
- [Macmillan](//www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/facebook)
- [Collins](//www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/facebook)
- [Longman](//www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/facebook)

Comment: Це важливо — знати, який наголос був у мові-оригіналі. Але наголос у мові-акцепторі не зобов'язаний збігатися з наголосом у мові-оригіналі (наприклад, хоча б [_login_ /ˈlɑɡɪn/](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/login#Pronunciation) → [_лоѓін_](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=197778&page=1522)). Фактично наголос визначається узусом.

Comment: Хоча здавалося б, у випадку власних назв ми мали б віддавати більшу шану оригінальній вимові. Але навіть у випадку власних назв це не завжди так. Я не знаю, чи є десь ця інформація в інеті (зосередж. в одному місці), але тут спадає на думку, як по-різному називають «三星 (Самсунг)» у різних країнах світу (зокрема різний наголос). Адже ми при транслітерації не ставимо собі за мету відтворити оригінальну вимову, корегуємо навіть серйозніші аспекти вимови, ніж наголос, під власні традиції. Коротко кажучи, може статися так, що _Facebook_ має один наголос, а _Фейсбук_ (укр. трансліт. назви) — інший.

Comment: Приєднуюся до попередніх коментарів. Цей допис не містить відповіді стосовно того, як ставиться наголос **в українському запозиченому слові**. Прикладів, коли наголос не відповідає оригіналу — море: наприклад, *Manchester* `/ ˈmæntʃɪstər /` або *Liverpool* `/ ˈlɪvərpuːl /`в українській ніхто не наголошує на перший склад. А про [YouTube](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/YouTube#Pronunciation) або *Інтернет* я навіть не згадую… :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/nagolos/nagolos-u-slovi-fejsbuk) 
[image]

> *"Цього слова ще немає в словниках, тому ми запитали в мовознавця
>   Олександра Пономарева. Ось його відповідь: «Наголошувати потрібно на
>   першому складі: Фéйсбук. Так кажуть англійці, і нам немає підстав
>   застосовувати якусь иншу форму». Джерело:
>   http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-41651236"*