# Як правильно сказати "запостить на Фейсбуке" українською?

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів, from-english, запозичені-слова

У розмовній українській мові дедалі частіше можна почути слово "**запостити**" у значенні розмістити певну інформацію (пост) в інтернеті (переважно у соцмережах).

"Пост" є запозиченим словом і походить від англійського слова "**post**", яке може бути як дієсловом, так і іменником.

Підтвердження цього тлумачення дає нам [Thesaurus Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/post):

> Digital Technology. an **online message** that is submitted to a message
>   board or electronic mailing list. text, images, etc., that are placed
>   on a website: a blog post.

[Тут](https://nv.ua/ukr/style/blogs/desjat-pravil-uspishnogo-posta-v-fejsbutsi-1888887.html) є один з багатьох прикладів вживання слова "пост":

> Десять правил успішного поста в Фейсбуці.

У російській мові активно зустрічається слово "**запостить в соцсетях**", зокрема [тут](https://www.gadgetstyle.com.ua/33248-facebook-instagram-photo-posting/).

*Чи можна в українській мові вживати конструкцію "запостити у соцмережах"?
І як правильно було б сказати "запостить на Фейсбуке" українською?*

Comment: Навіть не знаю… гм, гаразд, нехай буде родичі-запитанньа: [Чи є термін кращий, ніж **перепост**?](/q/1114/) — [**У Фейсбуці** чи **на Фейсбуці**](/q/488/)

Comment: Здається, все-таки [tag:from-english], бо у російській це слово є [варваризмом](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можу запропонувати наступний варіант: *дописати на Фейсбуку/Фейсбуці*.

Блог професора Пономаріва має таку [згадку](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2013/11/131125_ponomariv_blog_ko) про вживання назви цієї соцмережі:

> *Як відмінювати слово Фейсбук? Як уживати його у місцевому відмінку?*
>
> *Тут можливі обидві форми: на Фейсбуці і на Фейсбуку.*

Проект "Словотвір" має наступні варіанти перекладу українською англійського слова *[post](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/post)*:

- допис (найпопулярніший)
- запис
- замітка
- виклад
- публікація
- напис
- оповіщення

Наразі не спостерігається унормованого варіанту словосполучення, є і *[допис у соцмережі](https://24tv.ua/studenta_z_kpi_hochut_vignati_z_universitetu_za_dopis_u_sotsmerezhi_detali_n928223)*, і *[допис у Фейсбуці](https://www.032.ua/news/1963342)*, і *[пост у соцмережі](http://magnolia-tv.com/video-news/2018-03-27/105157-post-u-sotsmerezh-zmusiv-tsitrus-povernuti-kiyants-telefon-v-deo?page=2&prov=ukrnet)*. Але відмічу, що на пошуковий запит *пост на Фейсбуку* отримую результати російською, а не українською.

Comment: Мені здається, що запитання було са́ме про дієслово, а ця відповідь зосереджується на слові [«Фейсбук»](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/488/), на [наголосі](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3090/) і на іменнику «post».

Comment: @bytebuster, але ж дієслова треба від чогось утворювати.